# Lubuntu for older laptop?

Tags: lubuntu

I have an old Dell laptop with 128 MB RAM. It readily boots up and runs the Edgy Eft 6.10 liveCD. This liveCD has an old Firefox 2 on it which some websites don't like. I would also like to run Flash so I am thinking that Lubuntu is the way to go. Which version would allow install of Adobe Flash player or Google Chrome?

thanks

Comment: That's the bare minimum to **Run** Lubuntu, you might want  to install Fluxbox and use it instead of Openbox, and not Using Chrome or Firefox but a lighter browser like Midori and Flash is probably going to choke that laptop.

Answer (score 2):

Lubuntu is the best version to start with as it is going to be the lightest on resources.

But, that laptop is going to run slow. You might want to look at a light weight distro such as tinycore or slitaz.

Comment: Could you add some information about these?

Comment: There are several distros designed to be light weight. http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/ and http://www.slitaz.org/en/ are my favorite.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've tested tinycore and slitaz against Lubuntu on my 12 year old laptop and Lubuntu is faster than slitaz(installed on the actual laptop) and tinycore is cumbersome as hell and uses 64mb of ram (with nothing extra installed) off the back while Lubuntu runs at 58mb even if installation requires 128mb. I suggest using a 10.04 version of Lubuntu as your interface base (version you install) then using `sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo dist-upgrade` to update the core images. The new versions of the interface have unnecessary items due to their recent joining of the ubuntu family.

Answer (score 0):

Lubuntu works quite nicely on old computers.  On my old computer I have found the fastest web browser is Opera (which is not available in the repos.  Next is Midori which only barely beats Firefox, and last is Chrome (not sure why it is so slow... most people find it to be fast).  So I would highly suggest using Opera as your browser because it loads in less than half the time.  http://www.opera.com/  I would also suggest installing http://www.xnoise-media-player.com/ xnoise for your main music program.  It loads almost as fast as Audacious, but is much prettier than Rhythmbox and Banshee.  It doesn't support mp3 players quite yet or CDs... but it is loads fast and is beautiful for digital music.  I would suggest going with the LTS 12.04 instead of 12.10.  Also if you have an old nvidia graaphics card you will be stuck using the opensource driver (which is much better than it used to be)